# Pure abstract classes for input-, output- and bidirectional-pin of microcontroller

Tags: c++, embedded-systems, abstract-class

I'm writing a real-time operating system for microcontrollers in C++11 - [distortos](http://distortos.org). Currently I'm thinking about a C++ framework for various peripherals. The most basic peripheral which I would like to have there are input/output pins. Because such input/output pins can both be built into the chip or be external (I2C expanders, shift registers, ...) I plan to implement interfaces for them with pure abstract classes.

These are some of mine requirements:

- some pins can only be inputs and it shouldn't be possible to (easily) change their direction - for example if you change the direction of pin connected to push-button to "output" you can irreversibly damage the chip, the board or the device that is connected to the other side of the wire;
- some pins can only be outputs and it shouldn't be possible to (easily) change their direction - if you are using a HC595 shift register then this can only be "output" and nothing more;
- some pins can change their direction freely - this is required if you want to implement software I2C or software 1-wire;

Initially I have thought about doing it like this:

1. The most basic interface class would be `InputPin` - it would only support "reading" the state of the pin.
2. Second interface class would be `OutputPin` - it would inherit from InputPin (as you can read the value of pin configured as output) and also add the ability to "write" the value.
3. Third interface class - `InputOutputPin` would inherit from `OutputPin` and also provide a function to change direction.

Such approach has a very nice feature that I can use use any derived class in function that requires one of the bases. But actually there is one substitution that is not always correct - using `InputOutputPin` in a function that requires `OutputPin` can be a problem when the instance of `InputOutputPin` is currently configured to be an input...

I've tried googling around for some inspiration and it seems that there is not much to use. ARM's mbed framework has 3 completely unrelated classes (there is no inheritance there) - one for "in", one for "out" and one for "in/out". Most of the code that I found has only one class that is for "in/out". I've actually found an article about exactly the same issue that I'm facing - http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/108.php . The solution presented there doesn't suit my needs - in a multi-threaded environment the operation of changing the direction of the pin is not so simple and usually requires exclusive access to configuration registers (the change is a read-modify-write operation).

I wouldn't like to implement any solution where the functions could fail (for example return error codes when the operation is not possible) - this would really complicate the usage.

Implementing a type-conversion operator - so that conversion from `InputOutputPin` to `OutputPin` would be done in a function which also makes sure the direction is correct - is error prone, because the reference to `OutputPin` can be stored for later use and at that time the direction may have changed again.

Maybe I should just simplify the hierarchy - `OutputPin` and `InputOutputPin` would both inherit from `InputPin` (this would always be correct), so `OutputPin` wouldn't be a base for `InputOutputPin`. This looses some of the flexibility, but I'm not sure that such substitution would be required anyway.

Comment: How would an `InputOutputPin` react if the pin is configured for input and you try to write to it?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - this would be a problem of the user (; but in that case it would be evident - to use `InputOutputPin` as output you must make sure that the direction is correct. But this wouldn't be so evident when converting `InputOutputPin` to `OutputPin` and using it through reference to base class - in that case it can be assumed that the direction is always "output", which is not necessarily true in that case and cannot be ensured...

Answer (score 1):

Look at prior art - the Apple IOKit is the C++ framework/API for device drivers in OS X/Darwin kernel. Also, you may even get some inspiration from the Linux kernel - Torvalds is a famous C++ hater, but many drivers (e.g. USB drivers for 4G mobile modems) are using hand-hacked inheritance in C, and the driver code is often quite readable.